# Unicode Emoji Fitzpatrick Modifiers?

Tags: fonts, unicode, emoji

Is there any way to get Unicode Fitzpatrick Skin Tone modifiers working in Ubuntu?

For example, using U+1F3FD (  - http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%8F%BD ) I should be able to modify the skin tone of an emoji.

So  should render as something like [image] - instead, I see

I've [installed Microsoft's `seguiemj.ttf` as recommended](http://probablement.net/txt/emojilinux) but the colour changes don't seem to work - even in Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the `Emoji One Color` font from: https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font

*Full disclosure: I created it and just made it live a few days ago.*

> The font works in all operating systems, but will currently only show color emoji in Mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird. This is not a limitation of the font, but of the operating systems and applications. Regular B&W outline emoji are included for backwards/fallback compatibility.

[image: Unicode Emoji Fitzpatrick Modifiers in Firefox]

Comment: Works perfectly in Firefox!